# Conexion de winforms C# con SQL Server remoto

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con winforms la cual necesito que se conecte a un servidor remoto para compartir los datos en una intranet a diferentes maquinas.

El punto es que solo quiero instalar el SQL Server en el servidor y que las demás PCs se conecten al el.

Es posible y de serlo cual sería el formato de la cadena de conexion ya que mi formato actual es este

```
public ManejadorDatos()
{
    string usuario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usuario"];
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clave"];
    string servidor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servidor"];
    string dataBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dataBase"];

    Coneccion = new SqlConnection("user id=" + usuario +
                                  ";password=" + password +
                                  ";server=" + servidor +
                                  ";Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                  "database=" + dataBase +
                                  ";connection timeout=15");
}
```

Comment: Por supuesto que es posible. En cuanto a la cadena de conexion, te recomiendo [ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/),ahi tienes toda la información para cualquier tipo de base de datos

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es el problema, puedes conectarte remotamente?, se más explicito, así podemos ayudarte y puedes obtener respuestas mas rápidas.

Comment: No olvides encriptar tu appconfig, ya que despues de hacer el ejecutable el usuario podra ver tu archivo y su contenido

Comment: @JuniorZapata tienes que configurarlo para que acepte conexiones remotas http://www.blogdemegastar.com/2010/09/pasos-para-configurar-sql-server-2008.html

Comment: sstan preferi eliminar la respuesta ya que tengo un comentario indicando lo mismo, gracias por la recomendación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pueden ser varios factores, te recomiendo checar todo lo siguiente:

- Tu connectionString te servirá en el caso de que estés en la misma computadora o en una VPN con dominio Active Directory, en caso contrario o de que no estés familiarizado con el tema te recomiendo usar la conexión por usuario y contraseña de SQL Server como indica @randall-sandoval, para ello debes tener configurado SQL Server con [autenticación Mixta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuFIATd6jvc).
- Verifica que tengas [habilitado el acceso remoto a SQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHDbkgpXwuE)
  como indica @pedro-Ávila .
- [Abrir los puertos para SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/kb/968872) en el Firewall de Windows.
- Si te encuentras en la misma red o en una red remota con VPN debes de asegurarte de tener conectividad entre el cliente y el servidor, una forma de validarlo es con PING, siempre y cuando tengas permitido abierto el [puerto en el Firewall](http://www.blogdeprogramacion.com/2009/12/habilitar-ping-firewall-windows-2008.html).
- Si se trata de un servidor remoto detrás de un router o Firewall en una IP Pública, deberás abrir los puertos correspondientes para SQL SERVER y configurar el Port Forwarding a tu servidor SQL, te recomiendo habilitar el Ping en el router para validar que tengas respuesta del sitio remoto.

Este video cubre varios pasos de los anteriores, espero te sirva.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8jh4AYthH0

Comment: Si eso es lo que pasa, no habia tomado en cuenta el hecho de que no estaba en la misma red.

Comment: Si resolviste el problema no olvides poner palomita a la respuesta que más te ayudó. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

claro que puedes instalar el SQL en un servidor y que el resto de computadoras se conecten a ese servidor (de hecho esa es la lógica de una base de datos, que se encuentre en un solo lugar  -o un espejo en varios servidores- y que todas las consultas y transacciones se hagan ahí).

Ahora bien, lo que te recomiendo es que hagas un `connectionString` en el `app.config` o `web.config`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="NombreConexion" 
       providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
       connectionString="Data Source = 192.168.200.1; Initial Catalog = MiBaseDatos; User Id = Usuario; Password = Contraseña;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

El `Data Source`, es la ip del servidor o el nombre que tiene asignado, e `Initial Catalog` es la base de datos a la cual te quieres conectar, el `User Id` el nombre del usuario con el que te logeas y `Password` la contraseña correspondiente al usuario.

Ahora para leerlo, primero debes de tener agregado al proyecto la referencia a `System.Configuration`, después con la siguiente sentencia:

```
String miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NombreConexion"].ConnectionString;
Coneccion = new SqlConnection(miConexion);
```

Aquí te dejo unas referencias de un [video de Youtube (en inglés)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1EWUAYNA1g) y de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Intente tu solucion pero no logro conectarme a la base de datos creo que el SQL Server no esta configurado correctamente.

Comment: intenta en el `providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Lo mismo sigue igual. ¿como me aseguro que el sql server esta bien configurado?

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es hacer un ping desde tu computadora al servidor, debes fijarte que el FireWall no esté bloqueando la conexión, después sí tuvieras instalado SQL Server en la computadora cliente, intenta conectarte desde ahí, en Server Name, le das la opción de buscar más y buscas la instancia y conectarte con el usuario y contraseña, aquí te dejo un [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms345343.aspx)